# Jquery function not invoked

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqueryform

I'm trying to show a form on clicking #createbook followed by submitting the form via AJAX. For test purpose, I am trying to alert hello world on clicking #addme but its not working.But when I entered the on click function on the browser and it works. Can you guys help me figure this out. Thank you. :)

```
<div id="mode" style="display:none">

</div>

<script>
    $("#createbook").click(function () {
        $.get("BooksLibrary/Create #create", function (data) {
            $("#mode").html(data + '<button class="btn btn-primary" id="addme">Add Book</button>');
        });
        $("#mode").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title:'Add Book'
        });
        $("#mode").css({ "display": "block" });
    });


    $("#addme").click(function () {
        alert("hello world");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As your `#addme` element is added dynamically (and isn't present when you create your `click` event), you need to delegate the event to an element which exists when you create the event. We can do this , using [jQuery's `on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#mode').on('click', '#addme', function() {
    alert("hello world");
});
```

jQuery's website has a nice section entitled [Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). The first paragraph explains what this is in a hopefully easy-to-understand way:

> *Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.*

Comment: Works absolutely perfect !! :) Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @pghimire happy to help! :-) Please remember to mark the answer as accepted if and when you can!